# Finding if the list contains same data?

Tags: java, database

Here i want to get if the `list.cust.getComponentIdentification()` value contains same value then i want to pick that value.

```
for(CustomizableMenus cust : ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()){

                        cust.getComponentId();
                        cust.getComponentIdentification();
                        cust.getComponentName();
                        cust.getComponentState();
                        custList.add(cust);
}
```

If a user is having same `componentIdentification` then i want to find respective component identification.

Comment: 1.Your English isunclear. 2. What java library are you using? 3. You probably should not be looping.

Comment: sorry i am week in english.. i am using 1.8, my intention is i want to find if the list contains the cust.getComponentIdentification() value same then i want to find them.

Comment: Please: Edit your English to be clearer. Read about [ask]. Give example nput and output. Give a [mcve]. What is the full name of any software that you are using? What is the exact name of the library that you are using to access the database via Java? "1.8" is unclear. PS Edit clarifications into your answer. Comments are ephemeral; they are not for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I understand, you want to find if something from the list is the same thing as the user has.

Pretending there's an object "user", you can do something like this:

```
User user = new User();
for (CustomizableMenus cust : ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()){
    if (user.getComponentIdentification() == cust.getComponentIdentification()) {
        // do whatever you need with it.
        // you might also add a break here.
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it's not exactly what you needed, so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stream them and use a filter:

```
List<CustomizableMenus> found = ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()
    .stream()
    .filter(cm -> cm.getComponentIdentification().equals(componentIdentification))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If this answers your question, let me know and I will edit your question to make it clearer.